# Why there is no difference between shallow copy and deep copy for a list of immutables

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, deep-copy, python-internals

Suppose i have a python list `l` consisting of `immutables.`When i am doing a **shallow copy** and a **deep copy**, the result is same:

```
>>> a = (1,2) # immutable types
>>> b = (3,4)
>>> l = [a,b] # a list containing immutable types

>>> import copy
>>> y = copy.copy(l) # shallow copy
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(l) # deep copy

>>> id(l[0])
139857440375584
>>> id(y[0])
139857440375584
>>> id(z[0])
139857440375584 # all have the same id's , so all refer to the same object
```

Does it means that **shallow copy** and **deep copy** has a meaning only for collections of `mutable` types because `immutable` types never changes. 
But if we want to achieve a **deep copy** like behavior for the these type of collections how can we do that?

Regards.

Comment: All references to immutable objects always have deep copy like behavior (if you make a copy, you'll never see changes to the original reflected in it).

Comment: @thatotherguy the two collections will have different 'ids` and the 'ids' of their elements will be different too, means full duplication.

Comment: So you're just looking to see changes in the internal ids, and you don't care about the semantics of copying?

Comment: @thatotherguy, i understand the semantics.A shallow copy of a collection is a copy of the collection structure, not the elements. With a shallow copy, two collections now share the individual elements.

Deep copies duplicate everything. A deep copy of a collection is two collections with all of the elements in the original collection duplicated.

Comment: @thatotherguy,You said "All references to immutable objects always have deep copy like behavior".I guess it should be shallow copy like behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cannot change the immutable objects, there is no point in creating copies of the same while copying.

#### Shallow Copy

As per [`copy`'s source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/07a6fca7ff42/Lib/copy.py#l101), shallow copy of immutable types is done like this

```
def _copy_immutable(x):
    return x

for t in (type(None), int, long, float, bool, str, tuple,
          frozenset, type, xrange, types.ClassType,
          types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
          types.FunctionType, weakref.ref):
    d[t] = _copy_immutable
```

For all the immutable types, the `_copy_immutable` function returns the object as it is, during shallow copy.

#### Deep Copy

The same way, during the deepcopy of tuples, the object is returned as is, as per the [`_deepcopy_tuple` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/07a6fca7ff42/Lib/copy.py#l234),

```
d = id(x)
try:
    return memo[d]
```

Answer (score 2):

thefourtheye explains why there's no difference. If you want to do it anyways, you can kludge it by pickling:

```
import pickle

a = (1,2)
b = (3,4)
l = [a,b]

z = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(l))

print id(l[0])
print id(z[0])
```

Obviously, this should never be necessary.

Comment: Thanks,very helpful answer. +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, creating the small-integer objects is optimized. Even when doing a simple assignment, you can observe the same identification of the object even though they should not know each other:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 5
>>> c = 1
>>> d = 5
>>> id(a)
1815461288
>>> id(c)
1815461288
>>> id(b)
1815461352
>>> id(d)
1815461352
```