# Can't understand python shallow copy when working with int and str

Tags: python, shallow-copy

Python doc about copy

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

I think shallow copy should copy the reference of the list, so update the shallow_copy_list should also change the original list, but the first example doesn't work as expected.

Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:01:42) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
items_copy = items[:]
items_copy[0] = 'a'
items_copy == items
False
```

I think this is a shallow copy, and items_copy == items should return True but it's False.
But another example return True

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'value': 1000}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'chair', 'value': 300},]
items_copy = items[:]
items_copy[0]['id'] = 'a'
items_copy == items
True
```

References:

[Python Shallow and deep copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958168/python-shallow-and-deep-copies)

[Ned Batchelder - Facts and Myths about Python names and values - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)

Comment: Both integers and string are immutable - you cannot _modify_ them, you simply assign new value in place of old one. Old value is untouched (of course if it qualifies, it may be deleted by garbage collector).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:**Shallow copying** means the content of the dictionary is `not copied by value`, but **creating a new reference.**

Have a look at this example.

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'value': 1000}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'chair', 'value': 300},]
items_copy = items[:]
items_copy[0]['id'] = 'a'

print items_copy,id(items_copy),items,id(items)
print items_copy == items
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 'a', 'value': 1000, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 300, 'name': 'chair'}] 4455943200 [{'id': 'a', 'value': 1000, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 300, 'name': 'chair'}] 4455866312
True
```

---

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'value': 1000}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'chair', 'value': 300},]
items_copy = items[:]
items_copy[0]= 'a'
print items_copy,id(items_copy),items,id(items)
print items_copy == items
```

Output:

```
['a', {'id': 2, 'value': 300, 'name': 'chair'}] 4455943200 [{'id': 'a', 'value': 1000, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 300, 'name': 'chair'}] 4455866312
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
items_copy[0] = 'a'
```

Means "replace the item in `items_copy[0]` with `a`. It changes the object referred to by `items_copy` (and therefore changes all other variables that refer to that object, which in this case does *not* include `items`), but has no effect at all on the item that was previously in `items_copy[0]` (in this the dictionary).

This is similar to this sequence of events:

```
foo = {'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'value': 1000}
bar = foo
foo = 'a'
foo == bar
```

This would return `False`, because `bar` is still the (unchanged) dictionary object.

In the second case, you did not modify either list, but you did modify the (first) dictionary that is referred to by both copies, similar to this sequence:

```
foo = {'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'value': 1000}
bar = foo
foo['id'] = 'a'
foo == bar
```

This would return `True`. (This is slightly different from your second example because in this case `foo` and `bar` are not only equal but actually refer to the same object.)

Comment: Can I understand like this: Both copies reference the same dict, you change   the dict, so both copies change; Both copies reference the same int, but you can't change the int, you just rebind the value of items[0], so the items[0] changes but items_copy doesn't change.

Comment: It's irrelevant that you can't modify ints. You can't modify *any* object in Python by assigning to a variable that contains that object; that variable is replaced by the new object and the old object is unchanged. So `r=7` never changes the thing that `r` used to reference, and `r[8]=7` never changes the thing that `r[8]` used to reference (but does change the contents of the object that `r` references, of course).