# Why Deepcopy in Python not creating new objects for single int values?

Tags: python, list, copy, nested-lists, deep-copy

I need some clarification on this concept here, I am trying out `.deepcopy()` in python and I have read that:

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, ***inserts copies*** into it of the objects found in the original.

However, In my code below, I can see that IDs for `x[0] = y[0]` and `x[1] = y[1]`, but ID for `x[2] != y[2]`, which makes sense because it inserts copies of the object. But why is ID of `x[0]` equals `y[0]` and `x[1]` equals `y[1]`?

This is the code that I tried:

```py
x=[1,2,[3,4]]
y=cp.deepcopy(x)
print(id(x),id(y))

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(id(x[i]),id(y[i]))
```

Output:

```
923236765248 923256513088
140729072564000 140729072564000
140729072564032 140729072564032
923256458496 923256516928
```

Comment: You won't be able to verify this behaviour just using `int`s. They are optimised to have the same `id`. Try a simple wrapper around them and you will see that you get new objects.

Comment: I think this has to do with reference types vs value types somewhere in the interpreter

Comment: It only copies mutable objects.

Comment: @quamrana Just to be precise, that optimization is only done for small integers.

Comment: Pretty sure @quamrana and barmar have it right.  yes this is a deep copy, if you change the value at y[2][0] it will not change the value at x[2][0], but they will have the same id before the change is made.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714569/cant-understand-python-shallow-copy-when-working-with-int-and-str?rq=1

Comment: Every integer has same id upto a certain limit. Try `id(1)` a bunch of times and you will get the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this exanple, I am using `obj` as a wrapper around another value:

```py
import copy as cp

class obj:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'obj({self.i})'


x=[obj(1),obj(2),[obj(3),obj(4)]]
y=cp.deepcopy(x)
print(id(x),id(y))

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(id(x[i]),id(y[i]))
```

Output shows all different numbers.